# How do I fix AttributeError: 'series' object has no attribute 'columns'? in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm creating a bunch of excel sheets using pandas apart from I can only create the first 3 before the fourth one throws an error. I've identified that the error is in the column names somewhere, but I don't understand why they're not acceptable (if the column names are all numbers it works fine). All the column names have been sanitised so that there is no punctuation or whitespace in them and so that there are no empty words. I've tested that all the column names are alphanumerical (they are).

I've tried replacing the column names with numbers instead of terms and that worked. However I want the term names as the column names.

## Is acceptable and works

```
terms = range(0, len(terms))
vect_list = [range(0,len(terms))]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(vect_list, index=[1], columns=terms)
df1.to_excel("excelTest.xlsx", sheetname="sheetname0")
```

## Throws an error when it reaches this set of terms (there are 1956 terms)

```
terms= ['10', '1000', '104000', '11', '1100', '1155', '1157', '119', '11page', '12', '1220', '1240', '1241', '14th', '15', '15month', '16', '18', '186', '19', '1984', '1998', '1999', '20', '22', '23', '25', '26', '27', '29', '294', '3', '30', '300000', '31', '33yearold', '37', '4', '40', '41', '41st', '48', '483', '4th', '50', '55', '56499', '5yearold', '858', '911', '92', 'A', 'ALBANY', 'AP', 'Aaron', 'Abner', 'About', 'According', 'Activists', 'Administration', 'Africa', 'African', 'AfricanAmerican', 'AfricanAmericans', 'Africans', 'After', 'Al', 'Alaska', 'Albany', 'All', 'Allison', 'Although', 'Amadou', 'Ambulance', 'American', 'An', 'And', 'Anne', 'Another', 'Appeals', 'Appellate', 'Arbor', 'Army', 'As', 'Asian', 'Assemblyman', 'Association', 'At', 'Attorneys', 'Avenue', 'Barrett', 'Based', 'Beat', 'Because', 'Bellinger', 'Benevolent', 'Bennett', 'Black', 'Boodram', 'Bookstaver', 'Boss', 'Bridge', 'Bronx', 'Brooklyn', 'Brounstein', 'Bureau', 'Businesses', 'But', 'By', 'CAN', 'California', 'Capital', 'Capitol', 'Carolyn', 'Carroll', 'Caucus', 'Census', 'Center', 'City', 'Citywide', 'Civil', 'Clergy', 'Cohen', 'College', 'Commissioner', 'Committee', 'Common', 'Communications', 'Community', 'Complaints', 'Convention', 'Cooper', 'Cops', 'Corning', 'Council', 'Country', 'County', 'Court', 'Courthouse', 'Courts', 'Crime', 'Crowne', 'Culleton', 'D', 'David', 'Dec', 'Defense', 'Deliberately', 'Democrat', 'Dennis', 'Department', 'Detective', 'Diallo', 'Did', 'Dinkins', 'Division', 'Dr', 'END', 'Edward', 'Eight', 'Either', 'Empowerment', 'Epstein', 'Eugene', 'Even', 'FOLLOWS', 'Feb', 'February', 'Federal', 'Finding', 'Following', 'Ford', 'Four', 'Fred', 'Friday', 'Fund', 'Further', 'G', 'George', 'Gerald', 'Giuliani', 'Giulianis', 'Gov', 'Grady', 'Greer', 'Guzman', 'H', 'HERE', 'Harlem', 'He', 'Hill', 'His', 'Hispanic', 'Hispanics', 'How', 'Howard', 'Hughes', 'I', 'If', 'In', 'Indeed', 'Instead', 'Investigators', 'Irvine', 'Island', 'It', 'Its', 'Jackson', 'James', 'Jamie', 'Jan', 'January', 'Jennings', 'John', 'Johnson', 'Joseph', 'Joyce', 'Jury', 'Justice', 'Kadiadou', 'Keith', 'Kennedy', 'Kenneth', 'La', 'Landis', 'Last', 'Leffman', 'Legislative', 'Liberties', 'Long', 'Lou', 'Louima', 'Lynch', 'M', 'MATERIAL', 'MadikizelaMandela', 'Mair', 'Mandela', 'Manhattan', 'Many', 'Marc', 'March', 'Mark', 'Martinez', 'Mayor', 'McLaughlin', 'McMellon', 'Metrocard', 'Meyer', 'Michael', 'Michele', 'Miranda', 'Modern', 'Monday', 'More', 'Moving', 'Mrs', 'Ms', 'Murphy', 'Muslim', 'NAACP', 'NEW', 'NY', 'NYPD', 'Nelson', 'New', 'Nickerson', 'Nicole', 'No', 'None', 'Norman', 'North', 'November', 'Now', 'OPTIONAL', 'Oates', 'Office', 'Officer', 'Officers', 'Old', 'Omar', 'On', 'Once', 'One', 'Only', 'Pataki', 'Paterson', 'Patricia', 'Patrick', 'Patrolmen', 'Patten', 'People', 'Peter', 'Plaza', 'Police', 'Politically', 'Pope', 'Post', 'Proposals', 'Prosecutors', 'Puerto', 'Queens', 'Ramadan', 'Region', 'Rev', 'Rican', 'Richard', 'RiteAid', 'Robert', 'Rudolph', 'STORY', 'Safir', 'Saikou', 'Saiku', 'Sarandon', 'Saturday', 'Sean', 'Sen', 'Serre', 'Seven', 'Sharpton', 'She', 'Siegel', 'Since', 'So', 'Some', 'Soundview', 'South', 'Southern', 'Speakers', 'State', 'Stephen', 'Steven', 'Stop', 'Street', 'Sunday', 'Supreme', 'Susan', 'T', 'TV', 'Taurus', 'The', 'Then', 'There', 'They', 'Thirty', 'This', 'Three', 'Thursday', 'Times', 'To', 'Tracy', 'Trade', 'Trimble', 'Tuesday', 'Two', 'US', 'Under', 'Union', 'Unit', 'United', 'University', 'Up', 'Vada', 'Vennard', 'Visitors', 'Ward', 'We', 'West', 'Westchester', 'What', 'Whatever', 'Wheeler', 'When', 'Who', 'Why', 'Will', 'William', 'Williams', 'Winnie', 'Witness', 'Witnesses', 'World', 'Worth', 'Would', 'Wright', 'YORK', 'Yankees', 'Yes', 'Yet', 'York', 'Yorker', 'Yorkers', 'You', 'Zeidman', 'a', 'able', 'about', 'absolutely', 'abuse', 'accepted', 'access', 'accommodations', 'accompanied', 'according', 'account', 'accounts', 'accused', 'across', 'acted', 'acting', 'actions', 'activists', 'activities', 'activity', 'actress', 'ad', 'added', 'adding', 'advertisement', 'adviser', 'affect', 'afraid', 'after', 'aftermath', 'afternoon', 'again', 'against', 'agencies', 'agendas', 'aggressive', 'ago', 'agony', 'agreed', 'ahead', 'all', 'allegations', 'allegedly', 'allnews', 'allowed', 'allowing', 'almost', 'along', 'already', 'also', 'although', 'am', 'ambitious', 'ambulance', 'among', 'amount', 'an', 'analyses', 'analysis', 'and', 'anger', 'angle', 'angry', 'announced', 'annual', 'another', 'antiapartheid', 'any', 'anywhere', 'aorta', 'apartment', 'appealed', 'appeals', 'appear', 'appeared', 'appellate', 'applaud', 'appointed', 'appointees', 'approached', 'approved', 'are', 'area', 'argue', 'argued', 'argument', 'army', 'around', 'arrested', 'arrests', 'arrived', 'article', 'as', 'asked', 'asserted', 'associate', 'associated', 'assumption', 'at', 'atmosphere', 'attacking', 'attempt', 'attend', 'attention', 'attitudes', 'attorney', 'attorneys', 'autopsy', 'available', 'avoid', 'avoiding', 'awaiting', 'away', 'awry', 'back', 'backdrop', 'backed', 'backfired', 'balanced', 'baldly', 'bang', 'barrage', 'based', 'be', 'bear', 'bearing', 'because', 'become', 'been', 'beeper', 'before', 'began', 'begin', 'beginning', 'begins', 'behavior', 'behind', 'being', 'belief', 'believe', 'believed', 'bellwether', 'belongs', 'bench', 'beside', 'best', 'between', 'bewilderment', 'beyond', 'biased', 'big', 'black', 'blacks', 'block', 'blood', 'blue', 'blurring', 'board', 'bolsters', 'bombing', 'booked', 'boost', 'borough', 'boss', 'both', 'branch', 'brick', 'bring', 'broadcast', 'brought', 'brutality', 'brutalizing', 'brutally', 'building', 'bullet', 'bullets', 'burnish', 'bus', 'businesswise', 'but', 'by', 'ca', 'cable', 'call', 'called', 'calling', 'calls', 'came', 'camera', 'campaign', 'can', 'cap', 'capital', 'captured', 'car', 'careful', 'carnival', 'carry', 'carrying', 'case', 'cases', 'castlelike', 'catch', 'catering', 'caucus', 'celebrities', 'cell', 'census', 'cents', 'chairman', 'chamber', 'chance', 'change', 'channel', 'charge', 'charged', 'charges', 'chased', 'child', 'chilling', 'choice', 'choosing', 'cited', 'cities', 'citing', 'citizens', 'city', 'civil', 'civilian', 'clamor', 'clear', 'clearly', 'clerk', 'client', 'clients', 'climate', 'close', 'closely', 'closest', 'clothes', 'cold', 'color', 'colors', 'column', 'combat', 'come', 'command', 'commander', 'committed', 'communities', 'community', 'compared', 'compiled', 'compiling', 'complaint', 'complaints', 'completely', 'computer', 'concern', 'concerned', 'concerns', 'concerted', 'conclude', 'concluded', 'concluding', 'conclusion', 'condemned', 'conduct', 'conference', 'conflicting', 'conservative', 'considered', 'constitutes', 'constitutional', 'contact', 'contended', 'contends', 'contention', 'contested', 'context', 'continue', 'continued', 'contributed', 'controversial', 'controversy', 'conventional', 'converge', 'correct', 'couch', 'could', 'council', 'councilwoman', 'count', 'counties', 'country', 'counts', 'county', 'courage', 'course', 'court', 'courthouse', 'courthouses', 'courtroom', 'courts', 'cover', 'coverage', 'cracking', 'creating', 'credibility', 'credible', 'crime', 'crimefighting', 'crimes', 'criminal', 'critical', 'critically', 'critics', 'crossed', 'cruiser', 'cry', 'crystallize', 'current', 'customers', 'cut', 'cutout', 'd', 'daily', 'damaged', 'danger', 'dangling', 'dark', 'data', 'day', 'days', 'deadly', 'deal', 'dealing', 'death', 'debate', 'debating', 'debriefed', 'decade', 'decided', 'decision', 'decisions', 'declared', 'declined', 'deep', 'defendant', 'defendants', 'defended', 'defense', 'defensive', 'defined', 'definitely', 'degree', 'deluged', 'demand', 'demanded', 'demanding', 'demonstrate', 'demonstrations', 'demonstrators', 'denied', 'denounced', 'department', 'depictions', 'depraved', 'depth', 'described', 'description', 'deserve', 'detailed', 'details', 'determined', 'did', 'died', 'differ', 'difference', 'different', 'diminished', 'dire', 'directly', 'director', 'disagree', 'disappointed', 'disappointment', 'disciplinary', 'discrimination', 'disenfranchise', 'dismay', 'disobedience', 'display', 'displayed', 'disrespect', 'district', 'disturbing', 'diverse', 'diversity', 'divide', 'do', 'doctor', 'documents', 'does', 'done', 'dont', 'door', 'doors', 'doorstep', 'doorway', 'down', 'downtown', 'dozen', 'drawn', 'dressed', 'drew', 'ducking', 'dumbstruck', 'duration', 'during', 'duties', 'duty', 'dynasty', 'each', 'eager', 'earlier', 'early', 'earlymorning', 'eased', 'easier', 'echoes', 'echoing', 'economy', 'editorial', 'effect', 'effective', 'effectively', 'effort', 'elder', 'elected', 'election', 'elements', 'eliminated', 'elite', 'else', 'embracing', 'empanel', 'employees', 'encounter', 'encounters', 'end', 'endangerment', 'ended', 'enforcement', 'enormous', 'ensure', 'equally', 'especially', 'estimated', 'ethnic', 'even', 'evening', 'events', 'ever', 'every', 'everybody', 'everything', 'evidence', 'evolved', 'exactly', 'examination', 'examiner', 'example', 'examples', 'excessive', 'executive', 'exists', 'expect', 'expected', 'expects', 'explain', 'explanation', 'expressed', 'extent', 'extraordinary', 'face', 'facets', 'facing', 'fact', 'facts', 'fails', 'fair', 'fairminded', 'fairness', 'family', 'far', 'farther', 'fast', 'father', 'fatigues', 'favor', 'favorable', 'fearful', 'feel', 'feeling', 'feelings', 'fell', 'felled', 'felling', 'fellow', 'felt', 'few', 'fight', 'fighting', 'filed', 'filled', 'filthy', 'find', 'finding', 'finger', 'fire', 'fired', 'firing', 'first', 'five', 'fivemember', 'fixed', 'fixtures', 'fleeing', 'floor', 'focal', 'focus', 'focused', 'folks', 'followed', 'followers', 'for', 'force', 'forensic', 'formation', 'former', 'forth', 'fought', 'found', 'four', 'frame', 'framed', 'freeze', 'frequently', 'friends', 'from', 'front', 'frozen', 'fruitless', 'further', 'fusillade', 'future', 'gallery', 'gave', 'general', 'generic', 'get', 'gets', 'getting', 'give', 'given', 'gives', 'go', 'goes', 'going', 'gone', 'good', 'got', 'gotten', 'grand', 'granted', 'great', 'greater', 'green', 'greeted', 'grocery', 'ground', 'grounds', 'group', 'groups', 'grown', 'guarantee', 'gun', 'gunfire', 'gungho', 'gunman', 'gunning', 'guns', 'gunshots', 'had', 'hail', 'hailed', 'hallway', 'hand', 'handcuffs', 'handicapped', 'hands', 'happened', 'happening', 'happens', 'harmful', 'harshly', 'has', 'hat', 'have', 'he', 'headed', 'headquarters', 'hear', 'heard', 'hearing', 'heart', 'heartbeat', 'heighten', 'held', 'helmets', 'help', 'her', 'here', 'hero', 'hes', 'high', 'highly', 'highprofile', 'him', 'his', 'history', 'hit', 'holders', 'holding', 'holes', 'holiday', 'home', 'homegrown', 'homicides', 'honestly', 'hoped', 'hopefully', 'hopes', 'hoping', 'hotel', 'hotels', 'hours', 'houses', 'how', 'however', 'hue', 'human', 'hurt', 'idea', 'identified', 'if', 'ignoring', 'illegal', 'immediately', 'immigrant', 'impanel', 'impartial', 'implication', 'impossible', 'impression', 'in', 'inadequate', 'inappropriate', 'incapacitated', 'incident', 'incidents', 'includes', 'including', 'independent', 'indicate', 'indicated', 'indicative', 'indicator', 'indicted', 'indictment', 'indictments', 'indifference', 'inevitable', 'inevitably', 'influence', 'influenced', 'initial', 'innocent', 'inside', 'inspired', 'instead', 'intended', 'intense', 'intention', 'interest', 'interview', 'interviews', 'into', 'invested', 'investigate', 'investigation', 'investigators', 'invoked', 'irresponsibly', 'irrevocably', 'is', 'issue', 'issues', 'it', 'items', 'its', 'itself', 'jacket', 'jail', 'jeans', 'job', 'joint', 'judge', 'judged', 'judges', 'judgment', 'judicial', 'judiciary', 'jurisdiction', 'jurors', 'jury', 'just', 'justice', 'justified', 'keep', 'kept', 'kicking', 'killed', 'killing', 'kind', 'kit', 'knew', 'knit', 'know', 'known', 'lack', 'language', 'large', 'largely', 'last', 'lasted', 'later', 'law', 'lawmakers', 'laws', 'lawyer', 'lawyers', 'leaders', 'leading', 'leaning', 'least', 'leather', 'led', 'left', 'leg', 'legal', 'legislative', 'legislators', 'legitimate', 'less', 'lessen', 'lesson', 'level', 'liberals', 'life', 'lighted', 'like', 'likely', 'line', 'listing', 'little', 'live', 'lives', 'll', 'lobbyists', 'local', 'long', 'look', 'looking', 'lore', 'lose', 'loss', 'lost', 'lot', 'lull', 'made', 'magazine', 'maintained', 'make', 'makes', 'making', 'male', 'man', 'manager', 'manhandling', 'many', 'march', 'marched', 'marching', 'mark', 'matched', 'material', 'matter', 'may', 'mayor', 'me', 'mean', 'meant', 'media', 'medical', 'member', 'members', 'men', 'mentally', 'mention', 'mentioned', 'middle', 'might', 'million', 'mind', 'minorities', 'minority', 'minutes', 'misconduct', 'mission', 'mistake', 'mistaken', 'mistakenly', 'mistaking', 'misunderstanding', 'mobs', 'moment', 'money', 'monitor', 'month', 'months', 'more', 'most', 'mother', 'motion', 'motions', 'move', 'moved', 'movement', 'moving', 'much', 'murder', 'murdering', 'must', 'my', 'myself', 'name', 'named', 'nation', 'near', 'nearby', 'nearly', 'necks', 'need', 'negative', 'neighborhood', 'neighborhoods', 'neighbors', 'never', 'news', 'newspaper', 'next', 'nice', 'night', 'nn', 'no', 'none', 'normal', 'north', 'not', 'noted', 'nothing', 'notice', 'noting', 'notion', 'now', 'nt', 'number', 'numbers', 'numerous', 'object', 'observed', 'observing', 'obtained', 'obvious', 'occurred', 'occurring', 'of', 'off', 'offered', 'office', 'officer', 'officers', 'officials', 'often', 'omitted', 'on', 'once', 'one', 'only', 'onto', 'open', 'opened', 'operator', 'opinion', 'opinions', 'opportunity', 'opposed', 'oppression', 'opt', 'option', 'or', 'orchestrated', 'ordered', 'orders', 'organized', 'ornate', 'other', 'others', 'our', 'out', 'outlets', 'outlined', 'outpost', 'outrageous', 'outside', 'outstretched', 'over', 'overflow', 'overhead', 'overlap', 'overly', 'oversee', 'overwhelmingly', 'own', 'owner', 'pacing', 'packet', 'painful', 'panel', 'paper', 'papers', 'parents', 'parlance', 'part', 'particular', 'particularly', 'parts', 'passed', 'passersby', 'passions', 'past', 'pattern', 'pause', 'peddler', 'peered', 'peering', 'people', 'percent', 'percentage', 'perceptions', 'perfect', 'perform', 'performed', 'perhaps', 'period', 'person', 'personnel', 'pick', 'picked', 'picture', 'pistols', 'place', 'plain', 'plainclothes', 'plan', 'planned', 'plans', 'pleaded', 'pleased', 'pledged', 'pm', 'pocket', 'pockets', 'point', 'pointed', 'pointing', 'points', 'polarizing', 'police', 'political', 'politically', 'politicians', 'politics', 'polls', 'pool', 'poor', 'populated', 'populations', 'pose', 'possibility', 'possibly', 'potentially', 'power', 'practice', 'precluded', 'predominantly', 'predominately', 'prejudicial', 'prepared', 'present', 'preside', 'president', 'press', 'pressure', 'pressures', 'presumed', 'pretrial', 'prevail', 'prevent', 'previous', 'previously', 'primary', 'private', 'probably', 'problems', 'proceedings', 'process', 'professor', 'progressive', 'prolonged', 'promoting', 'proof', 'propensity', 'proposal', 'proposals', 'prosecution', 'prosecutor', 'prosecutors', 'prospective', 'protecting', 'protest', 'protesters', 'protests', 'provide', 'public', 'publicity', 'publicized', 'publicly', 'pulled', 'punished', 'pursued', 'pursuing', 'pushing', 'put', 'quantity', 'question', 'questioning', 'questions', 'quick', 'quota', 'racially', 'racism', 'racist', 'radio', 'rallies', 'rallying', 'ran', 'rant', 'rape', 'rapist', 'rare', 'rarest', 'rather', 'rave', 're', 'reach', 'reached', 'reaching', 'react', 'reacted', 'reality', 'realize', 'reappointed', 'reason', 'reasonable', 'reasoning', 'reassured', 'rebut', 'recalled', 'receded', 'receive', 'received', 'recent', 'reckless', 'recognize', 'record', 'records', 'recounted', 'recruit', 'red', 'reducing', 'referring', 'reflects', 'refused', 'rejected', 'relationship', 'remain', 'remains', 'remark', 'remarks', 'remedy', 'remove', 'removing', 'render', 'rendered', 'rental', 'repeated', 'repeatedly', 'replete', 'reported', 'reporters', 'representative', 'reputation', 'request', 'requested', 'requesting', 'require', 'required', 'researching', 'resemble', 'reserved', 'resident', 'residents', 'resist', 'respect', 'respond', 'responded', 'response', 'responses', 'restaurant', 'restaurants', 'result', 'resulted', 'retirement', 'reveals', 'review', 'reviewed', 'rhetoric', 'right', 'righteous', 'rightly', 'rights', 'road', 'robbed', 'robberies', 'room', 'roommates', 'rooms', 'roughing', 'rounds', 'ruled', 'ruling', 'running', 'rushes', 's', 'sad', 'safe', 'said', 'same', 'saves', 'saw', 'say', 'saying', 'scenarios', 'scene', 'scheduled', 'scrambling', 'search', 'searches', 'searching', 'seats', 'seconddegree', 'seconds', 'section', 'secured', 'see', 'seeing', 'seeking', 'seemed', 'seems', 'seesaw', 'segregation', 'seize', 'select', 'selected', 'selection', 'semiautomatic', 'send', 'sense', 'separate', 'sequence', 'served', 'service', 'services', 'session', 'set', 'several', 'severity', 'shadows', 'shaking', 'shape', 'sharply', 'she', 'sheet', 'sheriff', 'shields', 'shipped', 'shoot', 'shooting', 'shorter', 'shot', 'shots', 'should', 'shoving', 'show', 'showed', 'showing', 'shown', 'shows', 'side', 'signed', 'significant', 'signs', 'silent', 'similar', 'simply', 'since', 'sister', 'site', 'situation', 'six', 'slack', 'slight', 'slipped', 'smiling', 'sneakers', 'so', 'sociology', 'socks', 'sold', 'some', 'something', 'son', 'soon', 'souls', 'soundness', 'sources', 'sparked', 'speaking', 'speaks', 'special', 'specifically', 'speculation', 'spent', 'spike', 'splinters', 'splitsecond', 'spoke', 'spoken', 'spokesman', 'sponsored', 'spotted', 'sprawled', 'stage', 'standing', 'start', 'started', 'state', 'stated', 'statement', 'statements', 'station', 'stay', 'stayed', 'steeped', 'stemmed', 'still', 'stock', 'stonily', 'stood', 'stoop', 'stop', 'stopped', 'store', 'stories', 'strategies', 'strategy', 'street', 'streets', 'strong', 'strongest', 'strongly', 'struck', 'stunned', 'subject', 'subpoena', 'success', 'such', 'sudden', 'suddenly', 'suggestion', 'superintendent', 'superiors', 'supervisor', 'supervisors', 'support', 'supporters', 'supposed', 'sure', 'surely', 'surprised', 'surrounding', 'surveillance', 'surveying', 'suspect', 'suspected', 'suspects', 'suspicion', 'suspicions', 'suspiciously', 'swarm', 'swarmed', 'sway', 'sweep', 'sympathetic', 'system', 'tactics', 'tainted', 'take', 'taken', 'taking', 'talking', 'tape', 'target', 'teaching', 'team', 'technicians', 'television', 'tell', 'tension', 'test', 'testify', 'testimony', 'than', 'that', 'the', 'their', 'them', 'themselves', 'then', 'there', 'thereby', 'these', 'they', 'thing', 'things', 'think', 'thinking', 'thinks', 'this', 'those', 'thought', 'thousands', 'threat', 'threats', 'three', 'threw', 'through', 'throughout', 'thus', 'tidal', 'time', 'times', 'timing', 'tip', 'to', 'told', 'too', 'took', 'torrent', 'touched', 'tough', 'toward', 'towns', 'trained', 'trampling', 'transfer', 'transferred', 'transportation', 'travel', 'treated', 'treatment', 'trial', 'tried', 'trip', 'troublesome', 'trust', 'trusted', 'try', 'trying', 'turned', 'two', 'twohour', 'ultimate', 'unanimously', 'unanswered', 'unarmed', 'unbiased', 'unclear', 'under', 'undermine', 'underscored', 'underscores', 'undetermined', 'unfolds', 'unfortunate', 'unfounded', 'unidentified', 'uniformly', 'unit', 'unjustified', 'unmarked', 'unprecedented', 'unsuccessfully', 'unsupported', 'until', 'unusually', 'up', 'upcoming', 'uplinks', 'upon', 'upright', 'upscale', 'upset', 'upstate', 'urban', 'urged', 'use', 'used', 'using', 'usually', 'validated', 'various', 've', 'vender', 'vendor', 'venue', 'venues', 'verdict', 'version', 'very', 'vestibule', 'victim', 'victims', 'victory', 'video', 'videos', 'videotapes', 'view', 'views', 'violations', 'voir', 'waging', 'waist', 'waited', 'wake', 'walking', 'wallet', 'want', 'wanted', 'warning', 'was', 'watched', 'watching', 'wave', 'way', 'we', 'weak', 'weapon', 'wearing', 'wedged', 'weed', 'week', 'weeks', 'well', 'welldesigned', 'went', 'were', 'what', 'when', 'where', 'whether', 'which', 'while', 'white', 'who', 'whole', 'whom', 'why', 'wife', 'will', 'willing', 'windbreaker', 'window', 'wireman', 'wisdom', 'wise', 'with', 'without', 'witness', 'witnesses', 'wo', 'woman', 'wonder', 'wondered', 'wooden', 'word', 'words', 'wore', 'work', 'working', 'world', 'worldview', 'worried', 'would', 'wounding', 'wounds', 'wrested', 'written', 'wrong', 'wrote', 'year', 'years', 'yell', 'yelled', 'yellow', 'yes', 'you', 'your']
```

```
vect_list = [range(0,len(terms))]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(vect_list, index=[1], columns=terms)
df1.to_excel("excelTest.xlsx", sheetname="sheetname0")
```

## Error Message

as you can see it creates the first 3 excel sheets perfectly :/

```
Creating Excel Data
Creating Term List and Cleaning Up Sentences
TERMS TYPE:  <class 'list'>
TYPE:  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Creating Term List and Cleaning Up Sentences
TERMS TYPE:  <class 'list'>
TYPE:  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Creating Term List and Cleaning Up Sentences
TERMS TYPE:  <class 'list'>
TYPE:  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Creating Term List and Cleaning Up Sentences
TERMS TYPE:  <class 'list'>
TYPE:  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3test.py", line 53, in <module>
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheetname)
  File "C:\Users\annoy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2124, in to_excel
    inf_rep=inf_rep)
  File "C:\Users\annoy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 376, in __init__
    self.columns = self.df.columns
  File "C:\Users\annoy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5063, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Comment: what is columnName? Please show the variables.

Comment: it was something I forgot to change, I've changed the examples so that they should demonstrate the issue. columnnames should've been terms

Comment: `terms = range(0, len(terms))`  how does terms have a len before being assigned?

Comment: terms is the long list of words. I didn't put it twice because it would be annoying to read through D: sorry, this is my first post and it's a mess